# Most efficient way to check if object value exists in PHP 7

Tags: php

I have the following object in PHP 7:

```
(int) 0 => object() {
   'master' => null
},
(int) 1 => object() {
   'master' => true
},
(int) 2 => object() {
   'master' => null
},
```

What is the most efficient way to check whether `master` is `true` in any key of that object?

I could loop through the object and then set a variable, e.g.

```
$master = 0;
foreach ($obj as $key => $value) {
    if ($value->master) {
       $master++;
    }
}
if ($master !== 0) {

}
```

But this seems inefficient.

The object itself has other data in each node, this is a simplified example.

What I'm trying to write, in as few lines as possible is, *does any part of this object have `master == true`?* Or, looking at it the other way round, *are all my `master` nodes set to `null` on this object?* A return of true or false would probably suffice as the output, although a count would also be ok.

Comment: you should take a look at array_walk http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-walk.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you don't want to loop through the array, and the key of the "master" array is always "master", then this one-liner should do it:

```
$masterCount = count(array_filter(array_column($masterArray,'master')));
```

[*array_column*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)  is used to fetch all of the values of the "master" column, [*array_filter*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)  without a closure will automatically filter out empty values (false, null, 0) and [*count*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) of the new array will get you the amount of true values.

Comment: Nice one-liner. You should probably add that `array_column()` needs php 7+ to work on an array of objects.

Comment: Nice, thanks for the tip, it's probably in the docs though :)

Comment: I've updated the post to say it's PHP 7 I am using - so  this solution is great

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($value->master && $value->master !== null) {
       $master++;
}
```

Have a look to this table :
http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Answer (score 0):

Use triple equal

```
if ($value->master === TRUE) {
   // your code here
}
```